# Exception throw from a using block

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
try{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(...), Encoding.ASCII)){
        // Code that can throw an exception
    }
}catch (Exception error){
    // Display error...
}
```

What will happen to the `StreamReader` in case there is an exception thrown from within the `using` block?

Should I add a `finally` clause where I close the stream?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The StreamReader will be disposed automatically by the using, as it's essentially a nested try/finally:

```
try{
    StreamReader reader =  new StreamReader(...), Encoding.ASCII);
    try {
        // Code that can throw an exception     
    } finally {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
} catch (Exception error) {
    // Display error...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Should I add a finally clause where I close the stream?

No, the inner `using() {}` (which is in essence a try/finally) takes care of the reader.

This code is basically OK.

Answer (score 3):

The `using` block is the same as calling the `.Dispose()` method in a finally.  And `.Dispose()` on StreamReader calls `.Close()`.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(...)) {
    //do work
}
```

... is the same as ...

```
var reader = new StreamReader(...);
try {
    //do work
}
finally {
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `StreamReader` will get disposed. Your code is good.